# How does Cufflinks inject methods into Pandas even if imported before?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Cufflinks provides an interface between Panda's `DataFrame` and plotly `iplot` in the form of `DataFrame.iplot`. The first two output examples below do not surprise me, but the third does. Each is run in a new instance of iPython3.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.iplot

Out[1]: AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'iplot'  

import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf
pd.DataFrame.iplot

Out[1]: <function cufflinks.plotlytools._iplot>

import cufflinks as cf
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.iplot

Out[1]: <function cufflinks.plotlytools._iplot>
```

In the first we see pd.DataFrame does not contain `iplot` by default. When cufflinks is imported after Pandas in the second example, it could easily add an extra method to the `DataFrame` class to provide additional functionality. However, in the third method the `DataFrame` class will be defined during the `import pandas` statement after `cufflinks` has been imported. How is the additional method still added? This is definitely convenient, as my understanding of how the middle example *could* work would require always importing the libraries in order, which is undesirable, so I would be interested to know the trick used here.

Comment: Cufflinks loads pandas inside own source code; https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/blob/master/cufflinks/pandastools.py

Comment: This occurred to me as well, but even if I choose a different alias for pandas, i.e. `import pandas as pds` then I still find that `pds.DataFrame.iplot` exists as long as cufflinks was imported along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is because python [caches](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) the modules it loads. For example, all of the below expressions are true:

```
import sys.modules
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pds
print(pd is pds)
print(pd is sys.modules['pandas'])
print(pds is sys.modules['pandas'])
```

prints:

```
True
True
True
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know that! Based on your comment I tested the following: import a class A from module M, add a method f to class A, import module M as M2, and finally invoke M2.A().f(), which works correctly. This is very interesting behavior. It is convenient, but I could also imagine how it could cause some nasty bugs. In either case, I don't think this pattern occurs very often, but it is nice to know how it works.